# Angular 6 ngOninit not called going from child to parent

Tags: angular, angular6

Consider the following setup:

```
{ path: 'module1', component: Module1Component, children: [
    { path: 'component1', component: Component1Component, children: [
        { path: 'component2', component: Component2Component }
    ] }
] },
```

So based on the above:

- */module1* loads *Module1Component*
- */module1/component1* loads *Component1Component*
- */module1/component1/component2* loads *Component2Component*

Also

- *Module1Component* is the parent of *Component1Component*
- *Component1Component* is the parent of *Component2Component*

**Module1Component Code**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-module1-component',
    templateUrl: './module1.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./module1.component.css']
})
export class Module1Component implements OnInit {

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Module1Component');
    }
}
```

**Component1Component Code**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component1',
    templateUrl: './component1.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./component1.component.css']
})
export class Component1Component implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Component1Component');
    }

}
```

**Component2Component Code**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component2',
    templateUrl: './component2.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./component2.component.css']
})
export class Component2Component implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Component2Component');
    }

}
```

**ISSUE**

Given these links:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/module1']">/module1</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/module1/component1']">/module1/component1</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/module1/component1/component2']">/module1/component1/component2</a>
```

- When you are on */module1/component1/component2* and you go to */module1/component1* using the routerLink above the **ngOnInit of Component1Component is not called**.
- When you are on */module1/component1* and go to */module1* using the routerLink above the **ngOnInit of Module1Component is not called**.

**Conclusion**: The ngOnInit going from a child to a parent using routerLink is not called, why and how can it be configured to do so ?

**NOTE**: The same behavior occurs when using *router.navigate* or using the *back button in the browser*.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior that the ngOnInit is not called when navigating to the same component with different parameters.

But you should not call ngOnInit manually.

The subscription will get notified each time the route parameters change. So code within the subscribe method will execute each time. You don't need to call ngOnInit.

Try it by moving your console.log within the route.params.subscribe.